# I have an Excel "If" formula and it sometimes returns the incorect answer

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

My formula is =IF(K847<0,"Yes","No")
Where K847=0.00, formatted as "number" w/1000 seperator, w/-1234.10 chosen.
Answer supplied in the "L" cell formatted as, "General"

Cell K847 =0.00 and returns answer in L847 as "Yes"
Cell K846 =0.00 and returns answer in L846 as "No"

When I "Evaluate" the L847 formula, "IF(-1.45519152283669E-11<0,"Yes","No")"
When I "Evaluate" the L846 formula, "IF(0<0,"Yes","No")

I checked all referenced cells pertaining to K847 and all of them are formatted exactly the same way as "number". I need to know how to make the L847 formula evaluate to "IF(0<0,"Yes","No") like K846

Thank you for any help that can be supplied. I have been researching and am perplexed.

Anita

Comment: This problem comes from floating point imprecision (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel ). The question about why they evaluate `0.00` differently probably has something to do with one being "number" and one being "general"

Comment: I figured it out, I changed the formula from =IF(K847<0,"Yes","No") to =IF(ROUND(K847,2)<0,"Yes","No") and it works like a charm. Thank you all :)

Comment: Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out; I changed the formula from

```
=IF(K847<0,"Yes","No")
```

to

```
=IF(ROUND(K847,2)<0,"Yes","No")
```

and it works.